# Sorting array after firstName and lastName, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Currently I am sorting an array on firstName.

```
currentUsers = currentUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.firstName > b.firstName) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.firstName < b.firstName) {
        return -1;
    }
};
```

But I would like to have the lastName sorted as well. So that Bob Anderson would be sorted above Bob Bobson. I looked at another question here on stackoverflow which suggested that I should add:

```
currentUsers = currentUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.firstName > b.firstName) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.firstName < b.firstName) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.lastName > b.lastName) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.lastName < b.lastName) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

//Edit
The problem I have is that the sorting keeps sorting on every letter in firstName. How would I only sort on the first letter of firstName and then move on to the lastName?

Comment: Your first condition always fires return 1 or return -1 if firstName isnt equal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/awao21ug/1/ ?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is...

Comment: Just concatenate them `if ( a.firstName+a.lastName > b.firstName+b.lastName )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```js
var currentUsers = [ {
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Bobson"
},{
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Anderson"
}, {
  firstName: "Amy",
  lastName: "Jackson"
}];

var sorted = currentUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aFirstChar = a.firstName.charAt(0);
  var bFirstChar = b.firstName.charAt(0);
  if (aFirstChar > bFirstChar) {
    return 1;
  } else if (aFirstChar < bFirstChar) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    var aLastChar = a.lastName.charAt(0);
    var bLastChar = b.lastName.charAt(0);
    if (aLastChar > bLastChar) {
      return 1;
    } else if (aLastChar < bLastChar) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }    
  }
});

alert(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Comment: I had to edit the question, as I realized that my perception of what was happening was wrong.

Comment: Okay. Use `str.charAt(0)` to compare between the first letter.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this ES6 version

```js
const currentUsers = [{
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Adler"
}, {
  firstName: "Barney",
  lastName: "Jones"
}, {
  firstName: "Freddie",
  lastName: "Crougar"
}, {
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Adams"
}, {
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastName: "Lewis"
}, {
  firstName: "Joseph",
  lastName: "Lewis"
}];

const sortedUsers = currentUsers.sort((a, b) => {
          const result = a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName);

          return result !== 0 ? result : a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName);
        })

console.log(sortedUsers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just concatenate them with an underscore

```js
var currentUsers = [{
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Adams"
}, {
  firstName: "Barney",
  lastName: "Jones"
}, {
  firstName: "Freddie",
  lastName: "Crougar"
}, {
  firstName: "Bobby",
  lastName: "Anderson"
}, {
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastName: "Lewis"
}, {
  firstName: "Joseph",
  lastName: "Lewis"
}];

currentUsers = currentUsers.sort(sortOnFirstAndLast)

function sortOnFirstAndLast(a,b) {
  var aa = a.firstName + ", " + a.lastName,
    bb = b.firstName + ", " + b.lastName;
  if (aa > bb)
    return 1;
  else if (aa < bb)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

var $r = $("#result");
for (var i in currentUsers) {
  var div = $("<div/>").html(i + ":" + currentUsers[i].firstName + ":" + currentUsers[i].lastName);
  $r.append(div)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Not the solution, but that is my own fault, you did how ever make me realize what was wrong. This sorts on the entire firstName, that is every letter. Not just the first letter. Thats where I was confused and thought lastName was not sorting.

Comment: Concat only first letters of the firtname and lastName instead of the whole first/lastname.

Comment: Why would only want to compare the first letter? That would allow "Bob Adams" appear before "Barney Jones". If you want alphabetical by `first, last` then just put some characters between the two names that are `<` the letters. Like and underscore or a comma. "," < "A"

Comment: Yeah I know, but I have my reasons. But thank you anyway! =)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of alternatives. If you're only comparing the first char, you could use `charCodeAt` instead of charAt to get a numeric value for another way of comparing:

```
currentUsers  = currentUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.firstName.charCodeAt(0) - b.firstName.charCodeAt(0) 
        || a.lastName.charCodeAt(0) - b.lastName.charCodeAt(0);
});
```

The || executes only if the firstname first chars are equal (diff = 0)

Answer (score 0):

The best, shortest and most readable code I could figure out was

```
currentUsers = currentUsers.sort((a, b) =>
    a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName) ||
    a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)
);
```

'||' allows the other comparison only execute when first localeCompare returns 0, aka. both names being equal value.